# How do I add a custom attribute in amount/default.phtml?

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, price, magento2.2.6

I need to add in a couple of statements using some custom attributes for the Pricing. I am trying to figure out how to allow this to work. Right now I have this:

```
<?php
    $helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View');
    $_product = $helper->$block->getProduct();
?>

<?php if($_product->getData('show_price')): ?>
    <?php if($_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getValue() == 0): ?>
        <div class="price-box price-regular"><span class="price"><a href="tel:+1<?php echo $storeInfo->getPhone(); ?>">Call for Price!</a></span></div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="price-container <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAdjustmentCssClasses() ?>"
                <?= $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
            <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
                <span class="price-label"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayLabel() ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($_product->getData('priced_starting_at')): ?>
                <div class="price-starting-at">Starting at:</div>
            <?php else: ?>
                <div class="price-regular">Our Price:</div> 
            <?php endif; ?>
            <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
                <?= ($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
                data-price-amount="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>"
                data-price-type="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceType() ?>"
                class="price-wrapper <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceWrapperCss() ?>"
            ><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?></span>
            <?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
                <?= $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($block->getSchema()): ?>
                <meta itemprop="price" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>" />
                <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayCurrencyCode() ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is the error I am getting as of now:

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (LogicException): \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View doesn't extends Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper

Comment: Can you please share full path of your file?

Comment: app\design\frontend\Freshley\ultimo_child\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\price\amount\default.phtml

Comment: Its obvious to get this error because you try to call block function using helper.

Comment: Okay, so what do I need to do in order to get this working?

Comment: You want show your detail on product detail page or category listing page as well?

Comment: All of the above. This change should affect any place that shows the price.

Comment: You have tried to call `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` and that's for only product detail page?

Comment: I figured. Right now, I'm trying anything and everything that can get it working. I took out the helper as of now, and this is what error I get:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getData() on null in /chroot/home/davidfai/davidfairclough.com/html/app/design/frontend/Freshley/ultimo_child/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml:17